# saving values from jquery slider to different variables on click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

hey guys I am new to jquery UI.
Now I got this slider script.
please tell me how to save the lower and upper values to different variables on click
thanks.

```
 <script>
    $(function () {

        var minPriceInRupees = 0;
        var maxPriceInRupees = 500;
        var currentMinValue = 33;
        var currentMaxValue = 333;

        $("#slider-range").slider({
            range: true,
            min: minPriceInRupees,
            max: maxPriceInRupees,
            values: [currentMinValue, currentMaxValue],
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                $("#amount").val("Rs." + ui.values[0] + " - Rs." + ui.values[1]);
            }
        });
        $("#fromLabel").val("Rs." + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) +
            " - Rs." + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));
    });
</script>
```

And click is

```
     var firstVaal=$("#fromLabel").val("Rs." + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/5Kvk5/)**

code:

```
$(function() {
    var minPriceInRupees = 0;
    var maxPriceInRupees = 500;
    var currentMinValue = 33;
    var currentMaxValue = 333;

    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
        range: true,
        min: minPriceInRupees,
        max: maxPriceInRupees,
        values: [ currentMinValue, currentMaxValue ],
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
            currentMinValue = ui.values[ 0 ];
            currentMaxValue = ui.values[ 1 ];
        },
        stop: function( event, ui ) {
            currentMinValue = ui.values[ 0 ];
            currentMaxValue = ui.values[ 1 ];
            alert('currentMinValue and currentMaxValue updated !!!');
            alert('currentMinValue = '+currentMinValue+' currentMaxValue = '+currentMaxValue);
        }
    });

    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
" - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
});
```